# Creating a Resourse that has a Foreign key User

Tags: django, tastypie

I have a model that is related to a User. I have defined a resource for the model. I am having trouble Creating a new resource via post. I just get { "error": "" } back when I post:
{"user": {id:1}, "status": "Checkin to home."}
or 
{"user_id": 1, "status": "Checkin to home."}

Code is below. Any suggests would be highly appreciated.

Model:

```
class Checkin(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    status = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.status
```

Resources:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'user'
        excludes = ['password', 'is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser']
        allowed_methods = ['get']

class CheckinResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Checkin.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'checkin'
        filtering = { "status" : ALL }
        authorization = Authorization()
```

Comment: You need to send the users resource uri in your post data, not the django id.

Answer (score 1):

The json sent should contain the resource uri

eg 
    {"user": "/djangoapp/api/v1/user/1/", "status": "Checkin to home again."}

also if you want the created resource returned you need to set always_return_data = True

eg

```
class CheckinResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, 'user')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Checkin.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'checkin'
        filtering = { "status" : ALL }
        always_return_data = True
        authorization = Authorization()
```